# How do I update state with a button click when initial state is set in an useEffect hook api call?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am creating a list from an API call and then trying to sort the list with a button click. I have verified that the sorting methods work but state is not being updated/the list is not being updated. I think I am missing something with the useEffect. How could I do this better?

```
useEffect(() => {
  setLoading(true)
  async function getScores(){
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/scores')
    const body = await response.json();
    let entries = [];
      body.forEach((x => {entries.push([x.firstName, x.lastName, x.score])}));
    const sortedEntries = entries.sort((a,b) => b[2] - a[2]);
    setEntry(sortedEntries)
    setLoading(false);
  }
getScores();
}, []);

const sortByFirstName = () =>{
  const entryByFirstName = entry.sort((a,b) => {
    return a[0].localeCompare(b[0]);
    });
  setEntry(entryByFirstName);
  console.log(entryByFirstName)
};

return (
  <div className="ui segment">
  {loading
  ?
  <div className="ui active inverted dimmer">
  <div className="ui text loader">Loading</div>
  </div>
    :
    <div>
    <table className="table">
    <tbody>
      {entry.map((e) => (
      <tr key={e.id}>
        <td >{e[0]}</td>
        <td >{e[1]}</td>
        <td >{e[2]}</td>
      </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div className="ui button" onClick={sortByFirstName} >Sort by First Name</div>
  </div>
  }
  </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid mutating the existing state, you need to create a *copy* of the array in state before sorting. Change:

```
  const entryByFirstName = entry.sort((a,b) => {
    return a[0].localeCompare(b[0]);
    });
```

to

```
  const entryByFirstName = entry.slice().sort((a,b) => {
    return a[0].localeCompare(b[0]);
    });
```

Otherwise, if React sees that you've called a state updater with a value that's `===` to the value currently in state, it'll assume that it's the same, and so it'll skip computing changes.

Comment: You're an actual angel. Thank you!